# How do I reference subject of an email in camel route

Tags: java, apache-camel, jakarta-mail

I am trying to create a route the sends the message to different endpoints based on the subject of email received.

How do I referenct the subject in RouteBuilder.

I tried  header("subject").isEqualTo(...) and it is not working

Answer (score 2):

That worked for me:

```
choice()
    .when(header("subject").isEqualTo("My Subject")).log("YES: ${header.subject}").to("direct:subroute1")
    .otherwise().log("NO: ${header.subject}").to("direct:subroute2");
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using custom SearchTerm? It is available from Camel 2.11. From Camel docs:
`You can configure a searchTerm on the MailEndpoint which allows you to filter out unwanted mails.`
**Java Example:**

```
// we just want the unseen mails which is not spam
SearchTermBuilder builder = new SearchTermBuilder();

builder.unseen().body(Op.not, "Spam").subject(Op.not, "Spam")
  // which was sent from either foo or bar
  .from("foo@somewhere.com").from(Op.or, "bar@somewhere.com");
  // .. and we could continue building the terms

SearchTerm term = builder.build();
```

Comment: I am receiving the email , not sending it.Sorry for the confusion

Comment: how to  use SearchTerm it in routebulder